# How to resolve "path is undefined" error when using off() function in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a React application that integrates Firebase Realtime Database for real-time updates. I have implemented onValue() listeners to fetch data and keep it synchronized with my application. However, I'm encountering an error with "path is undefined" when attempting to detach the listeners using the off() function.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
  const listenerRefs = [];

  if (userInfo.chats) {
    Object.keys(userInfo.chats).forEach((value, index) => {
      const chatsRef = ref(getDatabase(), `/chatMetaData/${value}`);
      const listenerRef = onValue(chatsRef, (snapshot) => {
        // Data manipulation and state updates
      });
      listenerRefs.push(listenerRef);
    });
  }

  // Cleanup function to unsubscribe the listeners
  return () => {
    listenerRefs.forEach((listenerRef) => off(listenerRef));
  };
```

Despite following the Firebase documentation, I'm encountering the "path is undefined" error. I suspect that I may be using the off() function incorrectly or providing an incorrect reference for detaching the listeners.

Could someone please guide me on the correct usage of the off() function in Firebase Realtime Database to detach onValue() listeners? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `off()` function takes two optional parameters: `eventType` and `callback`. The eventType is a string that specifies what type of event to detach, such as `value`, `child_added`, etc. The callback is a function that was previously passed to `on()`.

In your code, you are passing a `listenerRef` object to the `off()` function, which is not a valid parameter. The `listenerRef` object contains the reference to the database location and the callback function, but not the event type. To detach the listener correctly, you need to pass both the event type and the callback function to the `off()` function.
you need to store the reference and the callback separately, and then pass them to the `off()` function along with the event type, like this:

```
const listenerRefs = [];

if (userInfo.chats) {
  Object.keys(userInfo.chats).forEach((value, index) => {
    const chatsRef = ref(getDatabase(), `/chatMetaData/${value}`);
    const callback = (snapshot) => {};
    const unsubscribe = onValue(chatsRef, callback);
    listenerRefs.push({
      ref: chatsRef,
      callback: callback,
      unsubscribe: unsubscribe,
    });
  });
}

return () => {
  listenerRefs.forEach((listenerRef) => {
    off(listenerRef.ref, "value", listenerRef.callback);
    listenerRef.unsubscribe();
  });
};
```

Comment: ohh so off() takes 3 params, ref, eventType and callback right. but what I dont understand is how did the listenerRef have ref and callback attribute. I tried console.log listenerRef[0].ref and it returns undefined.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, this will not work, because the Unsubscribe function does not have those properties. I updated my answer. please check it.

Comment: yayy it worked without any errors now. tyy. btw, could you mind explaining why we need to call unsubscribe() to detach when we already have off to detach.

Comment: Calling unsubscribe() is not strictly necessary if you have already called off() with the correct parameters. However, it is a good practice to call both functions to ensure that the listener is completely detached and that there are no memory leaks or performance issues. Calling unsubscribe() will also cancel any pending promises or tasks related to the listener, which may not be done by calling off() alone. Therefore, it is recommended to use both functions as a precaution and a convention.

Comment: ohh okk tysmm! ❤️